# Pdf Download but not Opening decoding error

Tags: servlets, pdf

This  is  my jsp   we  are  calling  an java method

```
<%
PDFFileUploader.generatePDcFile(); //Calls  the  PDF  method;
%>
```

This  is  my  PDFFileUploader code

```
public class PDFFileUploader {

    static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://localhost:7080/pdf/GetPDFFile";
    static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    public static void generatePDcFile() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Inside generatePDC File");
        // takes file path from first program's argument
        String filePath = "H:/report1.pdf";
        File uploadFile = new File("H:/report1.pdf");

        System.out.println("File to upload: " + filePath);

        // creates a HTTP connection
        URL url = new URL(UPLOAD_URL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // sets file name as a HTTP header
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("fileName", uploadFile.getName());

        // opens output stream of the HTTP connection for writing data
        OutputStream outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();

        // Opens input stream of the file for reading data
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        System.out.println("Start writing data...");

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        System.out.println("Data was written.");
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        //Read pdc file 
        //FileOutputStream test = new FileOutputStream("test");
        // always check HTTP response code from server
        InputStream test = null;
        File pdcFile = new File("H:/report123.pdf");
        FileOutputStream outputStreamTest = new FileOutputStream(pdcFile);
        //byte[] bufferTest = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        //int bytesReadTest = -1;
        //final OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/data.pdc");
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // reads server's response
            /*  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));*/
            test = httpConn.getInputStream();
            String message= httpConn.getResponseMessage();
            System.out.println("Message  is///"+message);
            System.out.println("Header :: "+httpConn.getHeaderField(0));
            final byte[] bufferTest = new byte[1024*14];

            while (true) {
                int len = test.read(bufferTest);
                if (len <= 0) {
                    break;
                } 
                outputStreamTest.write(bufferTest, 0, len);
            }

            outputStreamTest.close();
            test.close();
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            // extracts file name from header field
            int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
            if (index > 0) {
                fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                      disposition.length() - 1);
            }
            System.out.println("Get File Name"+fileName);
            /* Map<String, List<String>> map = httpConn.getHeaderFields();
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + 
                        " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());

            }*/
            // String response = reader.readLine();
            //System.out.println("Server's response: " + response);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Server returned non-OK code: " + responseCode);
        }
    }
```

from here  a  servlet  is  called  through  the  URL provided  above the  code for doPost  method  for  the  getPDFFile  Servlet is

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Gets file name for HTTP header
    String fileName = request.getHeader("fileName");
    File saveFile = new File(SAVE_DIR + fileName);

    // prints out all header values
    System.out.println("===== Begin headers =====");
    Enumeration<String> names = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = names.nextElement();
        System.out.println(headerName + " = " + request.getHeader(headerName));        
    }
    System.out.println("===== End headers =====\n");

    // opens input stream of the request for reading data
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();

    // opens an output stream for writing file
    /*FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);*/
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    System.out.println("Receiving data...");

    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    System.out.println("Data received.");
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    System.out.println("File written to: " + saveFile.getAbsolutePath());
    int processStatus = 0;

    //temp file (used for conversion)
    /* boolean success = (new File
                     (saveFile.getAbsolutePath())).delete();
    System.out.println("File deleted :: "+success);

    //delete pdc file too
    boolean successtemp = (new File
                     (recentlyConvertedFile.getAbsolutePath())).delete();
    System.out.println("File deleted :: "+successtemp);*/

    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream" );  
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=\"" + saveFile.getName() + "\"");  

    response.setContentLength((int) saveFile.length());
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(saveFile);
    //op.write(response.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")));  
    //op.flush();
    try {
        int byteRead = 0;
        while ((byteRead = fis.read()) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
        }
        os.flush();
    } catch (Exception excp) {
        excp.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        os.close();
        fis.close();
    }

    // sends response to client
    //response.getWriter().print("UPLOAD DONE");
}
```

The  file  is  getting  downloaded but not  opening the  generated pdf  have  the  same  size  of  the  original and  I  have  taken a  text file  and  printed the  content  to  another  file  it  seems  to  read  only  first line of  the  text  file  taken as  input

Comment: Can you share a copy of the file in the broken state?

Comment: The  Pdf  file  is not opening only I get the following error  "Adobe reader could  not open it it is either  not supported  file  type or because the  file  has been damaged"  pl help me Sir

Comment: Try to save it instead (e.g. using an attachment disposition) and then share it.

Comment: Here  is the  link  sir  ==> https://copy.com/LxUXSC3pS0ks

Comment: Ok, that file has absolutely nothing to do with a PDF (I thought there might be some leading or trailing garbage or some missing parts, but this is different).

Comment: Your code does not work because this is not a valid PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final loop returning a file from the servlet to the client looks like this:

```
    while ((byteRead = fis.read()) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
    }
```

You seem to have forgotten to use `buffer` in the `fis.read()` which should look like this:

```
    while ((byteRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
    }
```

Thus, you send back as many copies of the buffer contents as fis returns numbers `!= -1`.

BTW: Your servlet puts the data it receives into the `ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream` and drops that, but it claims to have written them into the file it eventually attempts to return to the caller.